# Getting value from 'time' type input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using React.
I have a few inputs:

```
  const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({
    model: '',
    manufacturer: '',
    year: null,
    startTime: ''
  })
```

which I get the values from them with this two-way binding:

```
 const handleChange = e => setInputValues({ ...inputValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
```

Works normally on all inputs (types `text`/`number`), but on the one with type `time` it doesn't.

```
<input type="time" name="startTime" onChange={handleChange}/>
```

I don't even get the event when I try to print `e` in `handleChange`.

What am I missing?

Comment: It is working as expected https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-williamson-1399u?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Insanely weird, in my machine it doesn't, not on Chrome nor Edge. Thought maybe its the React version, created a new create-react-app just for it but same. Tnx i'll just created a component to get the time

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it doesn't capture state updates in other to trigger a rerender.

Consider using the callback in [`React.useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) hooks.

Like this:

```js
const handleChange = e =>
  setInputValues((prevInputs) => ({
    ...prevInputs,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
}))
```

See a working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tmr8pt?file=src/App.js

Comment: Didn't help either, it doesn't even print e when u try to console log it. like the event doesn't register